# Chunk upload multiple insert

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Everytime a chunked upload is uploaded, all the chunks are inserted multiple times in the DB

each chunk = 1 insert to the database

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index = null, $content_range = null)
{
    $file = parent::handle_file_upload( $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range );

    if (empty($file->error)) {

        DB::table('test')->insert([
           'name' => json_encode($file)
        ]);


    }
    return $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved the problem.

In order to avoid multiple insert if using chunk uploads

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
                                      $index = null, $content_range = null)
{
    $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
        $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
    );


    // check if a file is needed to be chunked, 
    // if file is null, file does not need to be chunked otherwise file should be chunked upload
    if( ! is_null($content_range) )
    {
        // ex. the file is 1mb then last chunk would be 999,999
        $last_chunk = (int) $content_range[2];
        // get the filesize of the entire
        $filesize = (int) $content_range[3];

        // get the last chunk then add 1 to it and compare it to the filesize
        if( ($last_chunk + 1) === $filesize )
        {
            // db actions like insert to db or update something
        }
    } else {

        // other things
    }


    return $file;
}
```